# About Company Name Regular expression vvalidation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to Regular expression.
I have one requirement where i have to put validation on company name.
I tried various regular expression but did not match my requirement.

Here is my Requirement.
Company Name can contain dot, comma, space and (&) operator.
dot can be or cannot present at the end of string
Digits can also  be present

Accepted Criteria :
Welcome
Welcome & Welcome
3Welcome

Non Accepted Critria.
'dot'('.') cannot be present in middle of string.(like wel.come)
'and'(&) letter cannot be at end of string.
No other special character can be accepted.

Comment: *I tried various regular expression*. You should be able to include some of those various expressions in your post  then, to show what you've tried that didn't work for you. This is not a regex writing service.

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) apply to company names too.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to split it into 2 steps:

```js
const validate = name => {
  if (/[^\w,. &]/.test(name)) return false; // look for any not allowed char
  if (/\..|^\./.test(name)) return false; // test for dot
  return true;
}

const data = ['test', 'company name', '.not valid', 'not .valid', 'Welcome Welcome & Welcome 3Welcome']

for (const name of data){
  console.log(`[${name}] is ${validate(name) ? '' : 'not '}valid`)
}
```